# Upgrade Sitefinity 4.4

Tags: content-management-system, upgrade, sitefinity

I'm trying to upgrade my Sitefinity 4.4 website to 5.0. I'm trying to get the Project Manager 5.0 to do this upgrade as mentioned [http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/upgrading-you-sitefinity-4.4-project-to-the-latest-version] but I can't find. Does anyone know a workaround or if I can upgrade directly to 5.2?

Cheers

Comment: See the following forum post on Sitefinity.com. [http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/general-discussions-/migrating-4-4-to-5-0](http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/general-discussions-/migrating-4-4-to-5-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the documentation the upgrade path from Sitefinity 4.4 is:

4.4 » 5.0 » 5.2 » 5.4 » 6.1

You can download the project manager for each version by logging into your Sitefinity.com account to download the Sitefinity installer, but instead of the latest look for a link that says "Older versions".

Choose the most recent version of each major release, and be sure to download the ZIP of the Project Manager, not the installer.

I hope this is helpful!